# Shortlist - Multiple list validation and removal not working

Tags: entries, solspace-rating, listing

I have tried to use this below peace of code to auto add list for all the users.

Then based on user action try to remove entries from any existing list and add to new one that i wanted.

But multiple parameter passing with pipe is not worked, so tried to duplicate the parameter and no success.

any idea of how i can achieve this out of the box. or its simple not possible with shortlist.

```
<a href="{exp:shortlist:add entry_id='entry_id' list_name='Alist' remove_from_list_name='Blist' remove_from_list_name='Clist' }" class="prd-compare">
<span >Have this in "Blist"</span></a>
<a href="{exp:shortlist:add entry_id='entry_id' list_name='Blist' remove_from_list_name='Alist' remove_from_list_name='Clist'} " class="prd-writerev"><span> Move to Your "B list"</span></a>
```

My requirement is to build workflow of moving entries from one stage to another with single user action.

Appreciate any help on this - try to get some idea from add on developer but no success sofar.

let me update here if i get anything in the meantime

Thanks,
sus